# Can JS files be included in PHPUnit tests?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I am working on creating multilingual test cases. To achieve this I have to use the JS files that are used by the application. Is there a way to load those files into my PHPUnit scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, assuming you simply want to take an existing JS file and execute it's contents in Selenium. For that you can use the `file_get_contents()` function.

```
$script = file_get_contents('/path/to/your/script.js');
$this->execute(['script' => $script, 'args' => []]);
```